# php 7.1 with Apache on Windows 7 sp1 can't load sql server driver extension

Tags: php, sql-server-2012, driver, windows-7-x64

I can't load sql server driver in **php 7.1.** I followed all the instructions on **Microsoft** and **PHP** websites, did the procedure many times, but always the same end.
This is what i did:

1. download the drivers from https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=20098 and extract the files in `c:\php7\ext`
2. edit php.ini as in the screenshot and edit `extension_dir="c:\php7\ext"`
3. restart apache

I run SQL SERVER 2012.

Thank you in advance for your help.[image]

Comment: Did you add/check the `extension=php_sqlsrv_???_ts.dll` line in `php.ini`

Answer (score 0):

see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/php/system-requirements-for-the-php-sql-driver  which clearly states that SQL Server Driver for PHP 7.1 needs driver version 4.3, 5.2, or 5.3 **none** of which work with Windows 7.  The oldest supported desktop OS version for the 4.3.x series is Windows 8; and the oldest supported desktop OS version for the 5.x series is Windows 8.1